# TypeScript Typed Event Handler for a CheckBox

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an HTML input with the type `checkbox`. I can register a handler for the `change` event, and read the value like so:

```
  onShowCompletedTargetsChange(ev: InputEvent) {
    model.showCompletedTargets = (ev!.target as HTMLInputElement).checked
  }
```

This works fine, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way of writing the handler signature, so I don't have the explicit null check override (`!`) and casting (`as HTMLInputElement`).

Maybe it sounds stupid, but I was thinking about something like this:

```
  onShowCompletedTargetsChange(ev: InputEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    model.showCompletedTargets = ev.target.checked
  }
```

I tried finding it but found nothing.

Comment: I just tested this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-shadow-3o0g4?file=/src/App.tsx Looks like no need of null assertion

Comment: yeah, your `onChange` should have this type: `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`